# C# Accessing a list from multiple methods

Tags: c#, list, methods

I am looking to access a list from different methods in the same class.Is there an easier way to access the movieTitle list without making a new list for each method? Do I have to make a reference to the list in every method? or should I put them all into a separate class all together? My overall goal is to have a option menu that gets input from the user and depending on the input calls a method to list all movies, add a movie to the list, and pick a random movie from the list.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        optionMenu();
        Console.Read();
    }
    static void optionMenu()
    {
        Console.Write("(a)LIST MOVIES|(b)ADD Movie|(c)RANDOM MOVIE");
        string ui = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ui == "a") { printNames(); }
        else if (ui == "b") { addMovie(); }
        else if (ui == "b") { randomPickMovie(); }
        else { optionMenu(); }

    }
    static void printNames()
    {
        List<string> movieTitles = new List<string>();
        /*list.....
        / movieTitles.Add("Jurassic Park");
        /..........
        /..........
        */..........


        Console.WriteLine("Movies in your list...");
        for (int i = 0; i < movieTitles.Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t-" + movieTitles[i]);
        }
    } 

    static void addMovie()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
        string newTitle = Console.ReadLine();
        //I can't say...
        //movieTitles.Add(newTitle);
        //...? do I need to make an instance of the list?
    }

    static void randomPickMovie()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.Next();

        Console.WriteLine(movieTitle[random]);
        //same here. How do I access the movie titles in the printName()                 method so
        //I can randomly pick a movie from the list?
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you will greatly benefit from learning about the repository pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is one way make the movie list shared. This declares and initializes the list as a static member of the class (instead of a local variable in the methods).

This approach works well for simple programs, but having global state in a large program can be problematic because it becomes difficult to see which methods affect which global state so bugs can easily creep in. See below for another approach.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }

    static List<string> movieTitles = new List<string>(); 

    static void optionMenu()
    {
        ...
    }

    static void printNames()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Movies in your list...");
        for (int i = 0; i < movieTitles.Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t-" + movieTitles[i]);
        }
    } 

    static void addMovie()
    {
        movieTitles.Add(newTitle);
    }

    static void randomPickMovie()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Another approach is to pass the data from one method to another. This makes it more obvious to see what methods use the movieList. It also allows us to specify additional restrictions, e.g. you can see that printNames only needs a read-only version of the list so you know that printNames can't modify the list. This approach is a little more work but it's a good habit to get into because it reduces bugs in the long term.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }

    static void optionMenu()
    {
        List<string> movieTitles = new List<string>(); 
        string ui = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ui == "a") { printNames(movieTitles); }
        else if (ui == "b") { addMovie(movieTitles); }
        else if (ui == "b") { randomPickMovie(movieTitles); }
        else { optionMenu(); }
    }

    static void printNames(IReadOnlyList<string> movieTitles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Movies in your list...");
        for (int i = 0; i < movieTitles.Count;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t-" + movieTitles[i]);
        }
    } 

    static void addMovie(List<string> movieTitles)
    {
        movieTitles.Add(newTitle);
    }

    static void randomPickMovie(List<string> movieTitles)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295319/instance-field-vs-passing-method-parameter for another user's point of view on which approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

as for me, I prefer doing it this way.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 1)
        {
            movie.optionMenu(); Console.Write("Do you want to exit?");
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (response == "Y") { x = 1; }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Movie
{
    public List<string> movieTitles { get; set; }

    public Movie()
    {
        movieTitles = new List<string>();
    }

    public void optionMenu()
    {
        Console.Write("(a)LIST MOVIES|(b)ADD Movie|(c)RANDOM MOVIE");
        string ui = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ui == "a") { printNames(); }
        else if (ui == "b") { addMovie(); }
        else if (ui == "c") { randomPickMovie(); }
        else { optionMenu(); }
    }

    public void printNames()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Movies in your list...");
        for (int i = 0; i < movieTitles.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t-" + movieTitles[i]);
        }
    }

    public void addMovie()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
        string newTitle = Console.ReadLine();
        if (newTitle != "")
        {
            movieTitles.Add(newTitle);
            Console.WriteLine("New movie successfully added!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot add empty movie. Add movie failed.");
        }
    }

    public void randomPickMovie()
    {
        if (movieTitles.Count != 0)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int random = r.Next(0, movieTitles.Count - 1);

            Console.WriteLine(movieTitles[random]);
        }
        else { Console.WriteLine("Movie list is empty."); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for all your questions is create `MovieTitles` property of type `List<string>` and access it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        optionMenu();
        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<string> movieTitles;

    static List<string> MovieTitles
    {
        get
        {
            if (movieTitles == null)
                CreateMoviesList();

            return movieTitles;
        }
    }

    static void CreateMoviesList()
    {
        movieTitles = new List<string>();

        /*list.....
        / movieTitles.Add("Jurassic Park");
        /..........
        /..........
        */
    }

    static void optionMenu()
    {
        Console.Write("(a)LIST MOVIES|(b)ADD Movie|(c)RANDOM MOVIE");
        string ui = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ui == "a") { printNames(); }
        else if (ui == "b") { addMovie(); }
        else if (ui == "b") { randomPickMovie(); }
        else { optionMenu(); }

    }
    static void printNames()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Movies in your list...");
        for (int i = 0; i < MovieTitles.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t-" + movieTitles[i]);
        }
    }

    static void addMovie()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a title:");
        string newTitle = Console.ReadLine();
        MovieTitles.Add(newTitle);
    }

    static void randomPickMovie()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.Next();

        Console.WriteLine(MovieTitles[random]);
    }
}
```

`CreateMoviesList()` create list of movies only once and can be use to print movies, randon pick and add movies later on.